# "Data may still be loading"... but it's already there?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

So I'm running this code and all the points show up fine. But I still get the "Data may still be loading" tiles. I've double checked the table IDs, geocoding, column names etc... so now I'm at a loss. Anybody experience this before?

```
function changeByZip(formResults) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': formResults }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(13);
            layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Address' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Zip' = '" + formResults + "'");
            layer2.setQuery("SELECT 'Address' FROM " + tableid2 + " WHERE 'Zip' = '" + formResults + "'");
        } 
    });
}
```

I have two layers because I have about 14,000 points. When I comment out either one of those layers, the data loading tiles go away and it displays as expected. For some reason, the two layers don't like each other?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I discovered the column name was different from what the query was looking for.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Fusion but I have some ideas, maybe you can reduce your point data set with the LIMIT keyword to about 5,000 total points to see if that's the cause (too much data), and if it is, you will need to group your data prior to displaying it.

Comment: I will try that tonight. I'm skeptical only because when I go to the page all 14,000 points seem to show fine initially with none of those tiles. However, when I select a ZIP code, even one with only two markers, I get the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this link:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/troubleshooting

According to the troubleshooting guide:

**Map tiles "Data may still be loading" message does not resolve**

Cause: *Fusion Tables is unable to understand the query in the FusionTableLayer. A few things to try:*

- Check the query object syntax. Any syntax error can trigger this
  error message. To resolve it, fix your Fusion Tables Layers syntax.
  See FusionTableLayer documentation at Google Maps Javascript API V3
  Reference and Google Maps Javascript API Layers
- Check the Table ID. Doublecheck that you are using the correct table ID.
- Check column names. Column names are case-sensitive , so "Zipcode" and "zipcode"
  are not the same. Multi-word column names need to be enclosed in
  single quotes. See Fusion Tables SQL API: Reference.
- Check your geocoding. Fusion Tables must understand the locations in your table
  before it can map them. Location descriptions in your table, such as
  addresses, must be geocoded. See "Geocoding Location Descriptions" in
  the Fusion Tables Developer's Guide.

Comment: Checked the last three and everything seems right. Not sure about my query syntax, using "layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Address' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Zip' = '" + formResults + "' LIMIT 5");
    layer2.setQuery("SELECT 'Address' FROM " + tableid2 + " WHERE 'Zip' = '" + formResults + "' LIMIT 5");" This only displays the five results but still gives me the tiles. Sorry... trying to figure out how to format these responses.

Comment: What's the fusion tables Doc ID (or Tabled ID).

Comment: [Link to the map](http://res.dallasnews.com/graphics/2012_05/foreclosures/) Table ids are 3850410 and 3850507

Comment: A couple more comments. You're using the deprecated tabled ID.  See this link for more info: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Terminology.  Also, according to this query, your Zipcode field is numeric: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=DESCRIBE 3850410

Comment: Unbelievable. I checked the Zipcode column type and noticed that the column was called "ZIP2" and not "Zip" like the query was after. Oops. Thanks for getting me there. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Great. Might be worth updating your post so that it's in the initial body and/or voting my comments up :-)