# Error "Data may still be loading"

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm having the error "Data may still be loading". Drag or refresh the page to find out!" on my maps http://www.strahlen.org/map/map.htm.

My map pulls data from Fusion Tables. I didn't change my code or the FT since yesterday, everything worked fine, and the errors started this afternoon. When I choose "Visualize, Map" directly in Fusion Tables, the errors are also there, so the problem can't be in my site's html code.

Is this a Google load/performance error?

I have read https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/troubleshooting on the "Map tiles show "Data may still be loading" message, but the solution is not there other than F5/refresh... And I read this one ["Data may still be loading"... but it's already there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609186/data-may-still-be-loading-but-its-already-there), which doesn't solve my problem it seems because my table data looks ok, column headers match, table ID's are ok, etc

Thanks for help,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This happens periodically. Not sure the reason but it's definitely an issue with the Google servers and not your code.  It eventually goes away. Your map looks fine now.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Yes, it seems to be an issue "on the Google side" and after 24 hours it seems to be disappearing slowly. Thanks for your answer. And thanks to Kathryn also, who emailed me off-list. Cheers! Frank