# "Data may still be loading"... error :(

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Hi I have a map from fusion tables, located at http://andyinman.com/open-city/index.html. The fusion table is at https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1nZeH4nXDyPJX7iKKijMnBFWGtqI0vdy5xU74ANs.

There is a "Data may still be loading" error. I have used the exact same set of data before, but with different markers for the points, and it worked FINE. Can someone help?

Comment: Is it the same FusionTable as the "exact same set of data" you used before? If not, are the column names and types the same in both the tables?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003303/error-data-may-still-be-loading
It goes away after a while...

Comment: -geocodezip: it is a different fusion table. i changed some of the column names, but made sure to leave the columns that were used by the map the same (Location and Date).

Comment: -Frank: that would be awesome if it goes away. The difference between my case and the link that you posted is that my map works in the Fusion Tables ui map just fine, but doesn't work in my html. But i know my html is good because I was able to run my other map on it.

Comment: The usual cause of this problem is getting the query wrong, either the names of the columns or the "types" of the columns don't match the query (using number comparisons with strings, string comparisons with numbers).  Can you provide a link to the version of the map that works and the associated FusionTable?

Comment: What do you expect the query to look like? This is the best I can come up with by looking at your code, and it looks wrong (the three ' before type: searchStr = "SELECT 'Location' FROM " + fusionTableId + " WHERE 'Location' not equal to '''type' IN (-1,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) AND 'DATE RECEIVED' >= '" + $('#startDate').html() + "'";
searchStr += " AND 'DATE RECEIVED' <= '" + $('#endDate').html() + "'" + " AND ST_INTERSECTS('Location', CIRCLE(LATLNG" + results[0].geometry.location.toString() + "," + searchRadius + "))";

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid.

I can get it to work:

[SELECT 'Location' FROM 4720188 WHERE  'type' IN (-1,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) AND 'DATE RECEIVED' >= '1/1/2007' AND 'DATE RECEIVED' <= '1/30/2007' AND ST_INTERSECTS('Location', CIRCLE(LATLNG(39.770668,-94.846031),1000))](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=39.767040&lng=-94.846288&zoom=14&type=m&tableid=4720188&tablequery=SELECT%20%27Location%27%20FROM%204720188%20WHERE%20%20%27type%27%20IN%20%28-1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%29%20AND%20%27DATE%20RECEIVED%27%20%3E%3D%20%271/1/2007%27%20AND%20%27DATE%20RECEIVED%27%20%3C%3D%20%271/30/2007%27%20AND%20ST_INTERSECTS%28%27Location%27%2C%20CIRCLE%28LATLNG%2839.770668%2C-94.846031%29%2C1000%29%29)

or:

[SELECT 'Location' FROM 4720188 WHERE 'type' IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11) AND 'DATE RECEIVED' >= '1/1/2007' AND 'DATE RECEIVED' <= '1/30/2007' AND ST_INTERSECTS('Location', CIRCLE(LATLNG(39.770668,-94.846031),1000))](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=39.767040&lng=-94.846288&zoom=14&type=m&tableid=4720188&tablequery=SELECT%20%27Location%27%20FROM%204720188%20WHERE%20%27type%27%20IN%20%285%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%29%20AND%20%27DATE%20RECEIVED%27%20%3E%3D%20%271/1/2007%27%20AND%20%27DATE%20RECEIVED%27%20%3C%3D%20%271/30/2007%27%20AND%20ST_INTERSECTS%28%27Location%27%2C%20CIRCLE%28LATLNG%2839.770668%2C-94.846031%29%2C1000%29%29)

But even if I put the pieces that I believe are invalid into the query string there, I still don't get the dreaded "tiles may still be loading" message.  Try outputting the full query string you are using to a debug div on your page, then pasting it into the box on that test map.